# How can I generate salt and confirmation_token entries for migrated users with FOSUserBundle

Tags: mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am resurrecting a website that has been down for a few years and I am migrating everything to Symfony2.  I was able to get all of my old user database entries into the fos_user table.  The only problem is that the salt and confirmation_token entries are empty because users were were not created the standard way.  I want all users to reset their passwords, so I'm not worried about the old hashed passwords at all.  How can I generate the entries for 13,000 users at once?  Maybe I need to override the controller to create the salt and confirmation_token each time a password is requested?  Do methods already exist for this?  It seems like someone else would have had this problem before.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by overriding the fosUserBundle Resetting controller. [Instructions can be found here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html).

I forced generation of a new toke with these lines:

```
$tokenGenerator = $this->container->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
$user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
```

I was able to generate the salt values with a simple SQL query.

```
UPDATE fos_user set salt = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 31) WHERE salt IS NULL
```

Comment: Your link is dead. Could you update it please? Thanks! :)

Comment: Instructions are now here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html